# Get Absolute Path of Controller from ControllerContext object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, controller

I am writing an MVC app and am trying to override the RazorViewEngine with a new class. I would like to see what folders a particular controller is nested within.

If my project were set up as:

```
>MyProject
>>Controllers
>>>SomeGroup
>>>>AnotherGroup
>>>>>MyTestController.cs
```

I want to return "~\Controllers\SomeGroup\AnotherGroup\MyTestController.cs";

I have combed through the ControllerContext object for any paths.
I have also tried:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("MyTestController.cs")
 Path.GetFullPath("MyTestController.cs");
 Path.GetDirectoryName("MyTestController.cs");
 Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyTestController.cs");
 new FileInfo("MyTestController.cs").FullName;
 new FileInfo("MyTestController.cs").Directory.FullName;
```

Any ideas are appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: I should clarify a bit more. Any alternative options are welcome. I'm trying to match the folder structure of the Views folder to the folder structure of the Controllers folder. In the RazorViewEngine, I'm trying to create the actual path of the View from the current virtual path and controller path (which I can't find.) My class looks like this.

```
public class MyRazorViewEngine :RazorViewEngine
{
    public MyRazorViewEngine()
        : base()
{
    //Source: http://blog.thekfactor.info/posts/asp-net-mvc-custom-view-engines-using-the-razor-view-engine-as-the-base/
    ViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml","~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"};
    MasterLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
    PartialViewLocationFormats = new string[] { "~/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml","~/Views/%1/{1}/{0}.cshtml",  "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" };
    FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" };
}

protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
{
    string parentFolderPath = GetFolderNamesBetweenControllersFolderAndControllerFromContextObject();
    return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath.Replace("%1", parentFolderPath), masterPath);
}

protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
{
    string parentFolderPath = GetFolderNamesBetweenControllersFolderAndControllerFromContextObject();
    return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath.Replace("%1", parentFolderPath));
}

protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
{
    string parentFolderPath = GetFolderNamesBetweenControllersFolderAndControllerFromContextObject();
    return base.FileExists(controllerContext, virtualPath.Replace("%1",parentFolderPath));
}

}
```

I don't want to use Areas here. I'm simply trying to establish some hierarchy within the Views folder.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are also using the default routing to your controllers, then try:

```
Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath
```

Comment: I've tried HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath and controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath. Both return just a slash. No content. Thank you for the suggestion. The code is being called in a class inheriting from RazorViewEngine.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this a bit incorrectly. You don't need to return the file location of the controller ever... because it gets compiled into a DLL.

If you're trying to Hit a specific controller, MyTestController, you should just navigate to the following url http://www.example.com/MyTestController and the Index action of that controller will trip.

If that doesn't work, then there is a problem with your default Routing. Your RouteConfig.cs should have this :

```
routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Default",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Deposit", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```